# Django view-function for personal page of "author"

Tags: python, django, view

How can I pass information about a specific user and his messages to the view function?

For example, I write the following URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/leo.
Leo is the author of posts.
I already have a template to display all posts for a specific author.

Here is my view function:

```
def profile(request, username):
        user = 
        posts = 
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user': user, 'posts': posts})
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear.
The view function seems to be correct, but the question seems to be about how you can get specific information about the author and the author's posts.

The answer would be to get the Author information and posts, which is most likely from a data store (can be a MySQL, SQLite, or even a file).

Have a look at this [Django Blog application](https://github.com/addu390/django-pyblog) for reference.